# Android Eclipse Debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, variables, view, breakpoints

How can I see the ID of a view in the debug mode of eclipse? I know that you can browse the variables, but I am not able to find the ID value for a view/Spinner in that web of information displayed in the variable window.

Answer (score 0):

Run your application in the emulator and try 'HierarchyViewer` (Window->Open Perspective).